# Error importing a .pyd file (as a python module) from a .pyo file

Tags: python, windows, module, python-2.5

I am running pygame (for Python) on Windows. I have some .pyo files and some .pyd files. I have another script for somewhere else that is trying to import one of the .pyd files as a module but I keep getting the error that no such module exists.

Do .pyo files have issues importing .pyd files as modules? What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's typically because of one or more of the following:

- **The .pyd is not in your current path** (you said it was in the same folder so that should not be the problem)
- **A DLL the .pyd depends on is not in your current path.** Locate the missing DLL's using depends.exe or its modern [rewrite](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and either copy these dll's to the same folder or add the containing directories to your system path
- **You're using a debug version of python.** Then the module must be renamed from xyz.pyd to xyz_d.pyd.

Comment: Exactly the third one. I compiled the dll manually without the suffix of '_d' in a debug build, wasting half a day to figure out the import error!

Comment: It was the second bullet for me. I had to install [Dependencies by lucasg](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) as recommended [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244483/1048186) since depends.exe gives many false positives since it doesn't recognize API-sets.

Comment: Life saver.. I wasted a day of frustration.
It was the deps that where instantly solvable by lucasg info.