# How to debug C++ code that is called from Python that is called from MATLAB, using the MSVC debugger?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, matlab, debugging

**My setup**:

- Given some Legacy™ C++ code
- Using wrappers that use the [Python ↔ C/C++ API](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/index.html), this is compiled into a `.pyd` file
- There is a bunch of Legacy™ Python code that uses this `.pyd` file
- This Python code is then called from MATLAB
- MATLAB R2018a / Python 3.6 / C++11 / Windows 10 / MSVC 2017 Community
- This setup is rigid, i.e., all this code is used by 100s of people in all sorts of different contexts; this non-ideal setup is already the best possible trade-off

**The problem**:

- MATLAB crashes due to an Access Violation® somewhere in the C++ code.

Obviously, MATLAB can't "look through" the `.pyd` binary to determine the root cause, so this is all I have to go on.

**What I've tried**:

1. - Using MSVC2017, build the `.pyd` in `Debug` mode (`setup.py build --debug`).
   - In MATLAB: `pyversion 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe'`
   - Be **really** annoyed by having to restart MATLAB before you can actually do that.
   - After restarting MATLAB and running said command, in MSVC: `Debug` → `Attach to Process` → select `MATLAB.exe`
   - Run the MATLAB code that causes the crash.
   - MATLAB/Python complains: `Python Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`
2. - Try the same as in 1., this time renaming the `my_pylib.pyd` file to `my_pylib_d.pyd` (as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16937483/1085062) of all places...)
   - MATLAB/Python complains: `Python Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'my_pylib'`
3. - Try the same as 2., this time stating `pyversion 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python_d.exe'` (first making sure that a Python3.6 debugging environment has been installed in the MSVC context).
   - Be ***REALLY*** annoyed by having to restart MATLAB Every. Fucken. Time. you run that command!
   - Go to The MathWorks Support site and put in a Feature Request to try and get that fixed in R2019a
   - Restart MATLAB, re-attach MSVC to `MATLAB.exe` and repeat from the top
   - MATLAB/Python still complains: `Python Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'my_pylib'`
4. - Repeat 3., this time forcing MATLAB to also use `python36_d.dll` because somehow that mechanism seems broken in MATLAB.
   - SCREAM IN RAGE because you have to restart MATLAB **AGAIN** and not forget to re-attach to the `MATLAB.exe` process in MSVC **AGAIN**.
   - This time it at least continues with Python code execution, but it trips on *every* imported module (`numpy`, `scipy`, etc.) with the same `ImportError` as before ...
5. - Give up on Python3.6.
   - Try again, from the top, using a fresh, non-MSVC installation of Python 3.7, including debugging symbols etc.
   - in MATLAB:  `pyversion 'c:\wherever\Python37_64\python.exe'`
   - `<speak_angrily_through_teeth>` Oh. Yeah. I forgot. Restart MATLAB **AGAIN**, run `pyversion` command above **AGAIN**, run offending MATLAB code, SCREAM WHILE PULLING OUT HAIR because you forgot to re-attach MSVC, restart MATLAB **AGAIN** because it obviously crashed, re-attach MSVC, run offending MATLAB code `</speak_angrily_through_teeth>`
   - [Success](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuck_yeah)! MSVC goes to my API code after MATLAB triggers a breakpoint. The breakpoint is triggered here:

     ```
     PyObject *module = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
     ```

     where

     ```
     static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = 
     {
         PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
         "my_pylib",
         NULL,
         sizeof(struct module_state),
         my_pylib_methods,
         NULL,
         my_pylib_traverse,
         my_pylib_clear,
         NULL
     };
     ```

     After downloading the Python 3.7 source code, I can dig a bit deeper. The `PyModule_Create` call is a wrapper that calls the following function in `Objects/moduleobject.c`:

     ```
     PyObject *
     PyModule_Create2(struct PyModuleDef* module, int module_api_version)
     {
         if (!_PyImport_IsInitialized(PyThreadState_GET()->interp))
             Py_FatalError("Python import machinery not initialized");
         return _PyModule_CreateInitialized(module, module_api_version);
     }
     ```

     where the breakpoint is inside the `if()` clause. This means that the `moduledef` doesn't even matter. `_PyImport_IsInitialized()` is a function in `Python/import.c`:

     ```
     int
     _PyImport_IsInitialized(PyInterpreterState *interp)
     {
         if (interp->modules == NULL)
             return 0;
         return 1;
     }
     ```

     which doesn't seem like a very likely candidate to be causing my Access Violation®. Going into the `PyThreadState_GET()` finally made me realize: I'm actually debugging the Python/C++ API instead of my code...

**Questions**:

- What the heck!! Why is debugging in MATLAB using Python3.6 so damn difficult?! What is the "proper" way to do it? I can't find much in the (online) documentation for it...
- Is there a known issue with the Python 3.7 C/C++ API that could be causing this?
- Am I doing something wrong / stupidly? Any tips/pointers on how I can find the problem in my C++ code more effectively?

Comment: Did you find out where the code stops when the access violation occurs?

Comment: @AlanBirtles well, sorta...in Python 3.7 at least, it stops on that first (basic) object construction (`PyModule_Create`). With Python 3.6 (target version) I can't seem to get a debugger to work in this context ...

Comment: Thanks for the rant... doesn’t make the question easier to read though. :)

Comment: If the problem is in C++ code, why not call it from a stand-alone executable? If you need to debug the Python interface also, make a Python script that crashes, and debug from Python. There is no need to dig through so many layers! Also, instrumentation is your friend. If the out-of-bounds write triggers this, MATLAB might crash but a stand-alone executable might not. Instrumentation (e.g. sanitizer) might help find it quicker.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. It's true that these layers are in the way, and I'll definitely try to come up with a way to reproduce it outside of MATLAB. It's just that, I'd like to learn how to debug in this context because it's not going away anytime soon. And so far, only the MATLAB code has ever produced this particular problem - none of our tests or programs have ever found this problem. We compile with `/W4` and use basic static analysis (`CppCheck`), and all of these mechanisms are silent. I'll definitely give Sanitizer a try, though, sounds promising.